# flutter can't build lunch_url gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, url, mailto

i use `url_launcher: ^6.0.20` in my project and I added queries in android manifest:

```
<queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
        <intent>z
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

and added this:

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>https</string>
          <string>http</string>
        </array>
```

in info.plist

and here is my code example:

```
onTap: () { 
 launch('mailto:rajatrrpalankar@gmail.com?subject=This is Subject Title&body=This is Body of Email');
}
```

but when I run my project I got the error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':url_launcher_android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':url_launcher_android:classpath'.
   > Could not find builder-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.2/builder-3.4.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

can anyone help me please how can I solve it?